# Apache Log4j 2.17 version: ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '277050dc' at 'null' in 'null'

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I use Apache Log4j in my java project, in gradle:

```
api "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.0"
api "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.0"
```

I updated Log4j version from 2.8 to 2.17 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api)

and in a server log I see an error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '277050dc' at 'null' in 'null'
```

I found a similar error https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2901
in 2.13 version of Log4j, but any answers didn't help me to solve this problem.

Maybe somebody know-how can fix it problem?

In version 2.8 I didn't have any errors.. I think the problem in the new version 2.17, but I didn't found any think about this problem in 2.17 version of Apache Log4j

Comment: Seeing same error, watching.

Comment: @ctangudu do you have the same problem just with 2.17 version of Log4j2?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you found a fix for your problem. There are other, older answers posted on SO for the exact same error message. The issue has to do with the key used to set log4j configuration file. It has been updated from log4j.configuration to log4j2.configurationFile.